# boost::factory with std::map bad function call

Tags: c++, boost

I'm having a problem with understanding how boost::factory does its job. The following code will throw in the ctor of test2.

```
#include <boost/functional/factory.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

typedef boost::function<A*()> creator;
typedef std::map<string,creator> factory;

class A{
}

class AA : A {
}

class AB : A {
}

class C{
public: 
 C(factory& f);

 factory _f;
}

int main(){
 factory f;
 f["1"] = boost::factory<AA*>();
 f["2"] = boost::factory<AB*>();

 C test(f);
 C test2(f);
}

C::C(factory& f){
  _f = f;
  A* t = _f["1"]();
}
```

The message is

> terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl
>
> > '   what():  call to empty boost::function

I think I don't understand copy/move behaviour here and that is causing the problem.
As far as I understand, the factory gets copied in C::C, so every call to `_f[something]()` should get its own function to call. But somehow the function is moved out of the factory in the ctor of test, and then I get a bad function call, cause f["1"] is left in an undefined state.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I understand, the factory gets copied in C::C

Yes.

> But somehow the function is moved out of the factory in the ctor of test

Nope. If that seems to be the case you likely have [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) elsewhere. Or you might be running a  different (buggy) version of boost (this seems highly unlikely).

See if you can reproduce it with the code shown here:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c23b71dcbe244403)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/functional/factory.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

struct A {};
struct AA : A {
    AA() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }
};
struct AB : A {
    AB() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }
};

typedef boost::function<A*()> creator;
typedef std::map<std::string, creator> factory;

struct C {
    C(factory &f){
        _f = f;
        for (auto& e : _f)
            std::cout << "entry for " << e.first << " present " << (!!e.second) << "\n";
    }
    factory _f;
};

int main() {
    factory f;
    f["1"] = boost::factory<AA*>();
    f["2"] = boost::factory<AB*>();

    C test(f);
    delete f["1"]();
    delete f["2"]();
    delete f["1"]();
    delete f["2"]();

    C test2(f);
    delete f["1"]();
    delete f["2"]();
    delete f["1"]();
    delete f["2"]();
}
```

Prints

```
entry for 1 present 1
entry for 2 present 1
AA::AA()
AB::AB()
AA::AA()
AB::AB()
entry for 1 present 1
entry for 2 present 1
AA::AA()
AB::AB()
AA::AA()
AB::AB()
```